# File structure for storing pictures and files ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, file-io, web

I am trying to build a directory structure based on some object names and values to hold pictures and files, I am seeding some data into the DB and have a create option for the table in question. Where is a good place in the project to write this code to make it the least fragile?

Comment: Are you asking where to put the code files or where to put the files that you store in the application?

Comment: Hey Anders, Im trying to figure out in what part of the application to  write the code to do Directory.CreateDirectory("some path") etc.. Should it be in the controller, the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating the directory to store the files in is is part of global application initalization, I'd recommend to check if the directory exists and create it if it doesn't in `Application_Start()` in `global.asax.cs`.

Also note that adding/changing files to an ASP.NET site during runtime causes the application to restart (the idea is that you can update a config file, or an aspx.cs file and the change will take effect). For data files you don't want that behaviour, so make sure to place your files under the special `App_Data` directory that is meant for data.

Comment: So the directory name is based on the objects name eg "/tools/wrench/wrench.jpeg" do I have access to this data in 'Application_Start()'?

Comment: You should only create the base directory for the data in `Application_Start()`. Details directories that depend on the data should be created by the controller, or some kind of storage helper called by the model.

Comment: Ok thanks that was what I was leaning towards, I am not sure if the controller code is hit by Databaseinit.cs etc. so I will put the code in the model as you say